# Prove $\mathcal{L}$ is a complex vector space

Tags: measure-theory, vector-spaces, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

We define $\mathcal{L}$ as the space of integrable functions in a vector space.

Formally, given $(\Omega, \Sigma, \mu)$ a measure space, we define $\mathcal{L}(\Omega, \Sigma, \mu) := \{f:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{C} | \int{|f| d \mu} < \infty\}$.

So we have to prove this is a vector space over complex numbers. I’ve only found proofs of $L_p$ spaces being Banach spaces, but that’s not what I need.

Comment: If it's a Banach space, it's in particular a vector space.

Comment: @Wojowu that’s not what I’m saying, $L_p$ spaces are a quotient space of what I’m asking.

Comment: Integrability is not the same as $\int f d\mu <\infty$. What attempt have you made to answer the question?

Comment: @M.Navarro Ah, I see, my bad

Comment: Do you know that $|ax+by| \leq |a||x|+|b||y|$ for complex numbers $a,b,x,y$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to prove that something is a vector space, you have to check the axioms
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space#Definition

Note here that the elements of your space are functions $f$. Thus for example if you want to check if the addition of $f_1$ and $f_2$ are in $\mathcal{L}$ for $f_1,f_2\in\mathcal{L}$, you have to check the condition
$$\int |f_1+f_2|d\mu<\infty$$

You do this by using the linearity of the integral and the fact, that $f_1,f_2\in\mathcal{L}$. Thus, in this example
$$\int |f_1+f_2|d\mu \leq \underbrace{\int |f_1|d\mu}_{<\infty}+\underbrace{\int |f_2|d\mu}_{<\infty}<\infty$$

The first inequality here is the triangle inequality.
Do a similar computation for the other axioms to show that $\mathcal{L}$ is a vector space.

Comment: I agree that your inequality is true, but it isn't what I would call Cauchy-Schwarz.  It's just the triangle inequality pointwise plus the linearity and monotonicity of the integral.

Comment: Oh yeah you are right. I corrected my answer.